# Looks Like some Issue in the shortcode syntax or some PHP issues

Tags: php, wordpress

```
function some_shortcode($atts){
        ob_start();
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'option1'   => '',
            'option2'      => 1,
            'option3'       => 1,
            'option4'   => ''
            ), $atts ) 
         );
         $args = array(
        'option1' => $option1,
        'option2'    => $option2,
        'option3'     => $option3,
        'option4' => $option4
        );
        ?>
        <div class="classa <?php $option4==1 ? 'class2' : '' ?>">
            <span><?php echo get_theme_mod('newsletter_line_back'); ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="classb <?php $option1==1 ? 'class3' : '' ?>">
            <?php if($option2==1) {?>
                <h2><?php echo get_theme_mod('kirki_1'); ?></h2>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if($option3==1) {?>
                <p><?php echo get_theme_mod('kirki_2'); ?></p>
            <?php } ?>            
            //somecodehere          
        </div>
        <?php
        return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('some_shortcode', 'some_shortcode');
```

Although the above code is not throwing any fatal error, it is also defying the main objective.

**Suppose If I write this →**

```
[some_shortcode option2="0" option1="1"][/some_shortcode]
```

neither the `<h2>` disappears nor the `class3` gets printed.

I believe I am committing some syntax blunder.

help will be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: please check the error log and posti t as well..

Comment: no error log, but it si not behaving the way it is expected to behave: I mean no heading when set to off etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You have not used variable properly as you have declared it

```
 $args = array(
'option1' => $option1,
'option2'    => $option2,
'option3'     => $option3,
'option4' => $option4
);
```

I will only give one example next you sort out.. In these line

```
<div class="classa <?php $option1==1 ? 'class2' : '' ?>">
```

Targeting variable of array directly wont help your cause do something

```
<div class="classb <?php echo $args['option1'] == 1 ? 'class3' : '' ?>">
```

and yes you have not `echo` over there too... :)

You need to print that class right!!

Enjoy i have this work on my laptop..

Comment: when i sued echo previously it was generating error.

Comment: I have already done this bro calm down and read it out... how can u have class name without printing that class i think you have made other error u must do echo .. i solved this problem already in laptop

Comment: thanks sir. Give me some time I will get back to you.

Answer (score -1):

Here is correct code.

```
function some_shortcode($atts){
    ob_start();
    extract( shortcode_attr( array(
        'option1'   => '',
        'option2'      => 1,
        'option3'       => 1,
        'option4'   => ''
        ), $atts )
     );
     $args = array(
    'option1' => $option1,
    'option2'    => $option2,
    'option3'     => $option3,
    'option4' => $option4
    );
    ?>
    <div class="classa <?php $option4==1 ? 'class2' : '' ?>">
        <span><?php echo get_theme_mod('newsletter_line_back'); ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="classb <?php $option1==1 ? 'class3' : '' ?>">
        <?php if($option2==1) {?>
            <h2><?php echo get_theme_mod('kirki_1'); ?></h2>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if($option3==1) {?>
            <p><?php echo get_theme_mod('kirki_2'); ?></p>
        <?php } ?>            
        //somecodehere          
    </div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
```

}
add_shortcode('some_shortcode', 'some_shortcode');

Comment: what was my mistake? I could not see any difference.

Comment: You made the code even worse by replacing `shortcode_atts` with `shortcode_attr`

Comment: Yes, he is simply making thing worse, instead of rendering any help.